# Peewee getting column after join

Tags: python, mysql, peewee

I am unable to read the column of another table which is joined. It throws AttributeError

```
class Component(Model):
  id = IntegerField(primary_key=True)
  title = CharField()

class GroupComponentMap(Model):
  group = ForeignKeyField(Component, related_name='group_fk')
  service = ForeignKeyField(Component, related_name='service_fk')
```

Now the query is

```
comp = (Component
        .select(Component, GroupComponent.group.alias('group_id'))
        .join(GroupComponent, on=(Component.id == GroupComponent.group))
       )

for row in comp:
  print row.group_id
```

Now I get an error `AttributeError: 'Component' object has no attribute 'group_id'`

Comment: row has attrs `id` and `title`, what do you mean by `group_id`?

Comment: in the `select` i have added `GroupComponent.group.alias('group_id')` so I want to get the value of `group_id`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you just want to directly patch the `group_id` attribute onto the selected `Component`, call `.naive()`. This instructs peewee that you don't want to reconstruct the graph of joined models -- you just want all attributes patched onto a single Component instance:

```
for row in comp.naive():
    print row.group_id  # This will work now.
```